# Given a podspec file, what do I then do to include it in my project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, cocoapods, afoauth2client

[AFOAuth2Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client#example-usage) has a podspec file, which leads me to think it supports Cocoapods. How do I include it in a project? There's normally a "how to install with Cocoapods" section but I don't see one.

Comment: The process of adding a dependency through cocoapods is straight forward. Create a podfile with 'pods' and then then install cocoapods dependency manager as mentioned [here](http://beta.cocoapods.org/?q=) through terminal.

Comment: I know that. I'm wondering what line I add to my pod file.

Comment: The quickest way would be to find through the terminal `$ pod search AFOAuth2Client` would get you the 'podname'.

Comment: But what if it's not listed in the official Cocoapods directory? Such as a pull request with a new podspec? (e.g.: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below line in your podfile:

```
pod 'AFOAuth2Client'
```

btw: you can check  [CocoaPods/Specs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) to find if a project can add by Cocoapods

Comment: Is that given in the podspec? Or did you just check that site?

Answer (score 4):

The pod spec contains all the information you need to include it in a project. Just open the pod spec, you can do it in github, and check the name and version section.

s.name     = 'AFOAuth2Client'

s.version  = '0.1.2'

Every pod spec has these information inside. So now to include this in your project, you simply do this:

```
pod 'NAME', '~> VERSION'
```

so in this case

```
pod 'AFOAuth2Client', '~> 0.1.2'
```

Comment: But what if it's not listed in the official Cocoapods directory? Such as a pull request with a new podspec? (e.g.: github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55)